# How to login to application using user's Twitter account?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, social-framework

How can I create a login page where a user can login using their twitter identity.

I am running iOS7, So I have created a single page app.
I have added Social framework and added

```
#import <Social/Social.h>
```

I am wanting to keep the application as streamline as possible so when the application first loads, and loads each time there after I am checking if the user is signed into the app if not then I would like them to sign in using their twitter account.

I will check this here in the app delegate

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

However, I don't know how to sign in using Twitter.

Everything out there at the moment is focused around posting things to Twitter, I don't care about any of that. I want to know about using Twitter to sign into your app. and then what ever relevant issues I need to know. What data should I store to check when the user loads the app in the future etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow following tutorial for twitter integration using user account.
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Twitter_Integration_Tutorial_using_SLRequest
if do you want to make custom twitter login than you can follow following url
http://codegerms.com/login-with-twitter-example-with-ios-tutorial-using-oauth/

Answer (score 0):

Follow these two tutorial

First get access token, for getting access token follow the following tutorial.

http://codegerms.com/login-with-twitter-example-with-ios-tutorial-using-oauth/

Then using access token get account details, for getting account details follow following tutorial

http://codegerms.com/get-user-info-data-twitter-api-example-ios-objective-c/